# RestSharp - Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active clients reached

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to communication with an Web Service.

I use this code

```
public static object GetTagValue(string url, string tagname, out string resp)
{
    object result = null;
    resp = string.Empty;
    string theReq = string.Format("tags/{0}", tagname);
    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest(theReq, Method.GET);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    resp = response.Content;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resp))
    {
        dynamic json = JValue.Parse(resp);
        if (null != json.value)
        {
            result = json.value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Call to the server**

> GET http://ame-hp/tags/int32 HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json,
>   text/javascript, text/xml
>
> User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0
>
> Host: ame-hp
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

**Response from the server for a working call:**

> HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
>
> Server: Internet Pack HTTP Server
>
> Connection: Close
>
> Set-Cookie: SID=f11985564d;Expires=Fri, 27 Jan 2017 07:52:17
>   GMT;Path=/
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 133
>
> {"quality":"Good","description":"","name":"int32","value":0,"dataType":"int32","controllers":[],"initialValue":null,"readonly":false}

It's working but after two calls the service answers with this

```
{"Code":503,"Message":"Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active clients reached."}
```

**Third call to server**

> GET http://ame-hp/tags/int32 HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json,
>   text/javascript, text/xml
>
> User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0
>
> Host: ame-hp
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive

**Response from the server for all calls from now and until the server is restarted**

> HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active clients
>   reached.
>
> Server: Internet Pack HTTP Server
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 88
>
> {"Code":503,"Message":"Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active
>   clients reached."}

So I assume that the service has a limit of two clients.
But why do there exist two active clients?

Either the Server or RestSharp is not closing the connection, but which?

Is there something I can do in RestSharp to close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, as I assumed, that the server only allows 2 clients. On the first connection a Session Cookie is sent back and this has to be used for the rest of the calls.

In RestSharp you only need to add one line to make this happen

After creating the client (which by the way you need to reuse for all the calls). You add this line:

```
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

The initialization of the client would be

```
client = new RestClient();
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

Then you can use

```
client.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);
```

To set the url you want to call